# How do i fully delete my Biology Stack-exchange account?

Tags: support, moderation

I want to delete my account, is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, its possible through two different ways:

1. If you have posted only once, you can self-delete the account from your profile page, see [*How do I delete my account?*](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account).
2. If you have posted more than once or voted, you can request deletion through [the contact page](https://biology.stackexchange.com/contact) (select "I need to delete my user profile" in the drop down menu)

Also see [this meta.stackexchange post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account).

Why do you want to delete your account?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'll have to use the contact form :P Do i need to delete my old posts, or is done automatically?

Comment: I just don't enjoy using Biology.stackexhcange anymore. Mostly due to there being too conflict and bias on the site, in my opinion. Also, the voting system is very odd and subject to much foul play.

Comment: I dont think you need to delete anything manually, and I don't think you **can** delete upvoted posts - they will remain, but without reference to your user name.

Comment: I'll give it a shot and see how it turns out. Thanks again.

Comment: @R.Doto You're welcome. And sorry to hear that you find the site too full of conflicts. You can get that in the comments to individual posts, but I think its fine overall. And you can always ignore stupidity.

Comment: Very true. Although, when I ignore them, they just chose to down-vote my answer, instead. Even when I do reply, I still get down-voted since, i find it difficult to empathize my point without coming across as brazen.

Comment: @fuq Many of your posts are upvoted. Why bother about one rare occasion? Sorry to hear about your bad experience. We would wish that you do not delete your account and hope that you would have a better experience.

Comment: @fuq Thank you; you're right. There's no need to fully "rage quit" just yet. Especially over seemingly fickle matters. :)